# OSX stackshot format

Tags: macos, stack

I have a stackshot file and I'm trying to figure out what's going on in it. Here's a thread from one of the processes in it (this is from WindowServer):

```
  Thread 0xf09            1000 samples (1-1000)   priority 79 (base 79)   cpu time 0.044s
  1000  thread_start + 13 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 4981) [0x7fff952b3375]
    1000  _pthread_start + 168 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 15248) [0x7fff952b5b90]
      1000  _pthread_body + 131 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 15379) [0x7fff952b5c13]
        1000  thread_fun + 25 (QuartzCore + 129849) [0x7fff816e1b39]
          993  CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 257 (QuartzCore + 130113) [0x7fff816e1c41]
            993  mach_msg_trap + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 70534) [0x7fff8f639386]
             *992  ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 (kernel + 828992) [0xffffff80002ca640]
             *1    Thread_continue + 8 (kernel + 1879576) [0xffffff80003cae18]
               *1    thread_continue + 67 (kernel + 1001955) [0xffffff80002f49e3] (running)
          7    CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 563 (QuartzCore + 130419) [0x7fff816e1d73]
            7    CA::Render::Server::ReceivedMessage::dispatch() + 31 (QuartzCore + 1031139) [0x7fff817bdbe3]
              6    CA::Render::Server::ReceivedMessage::run_command_stream() + 567 (QuartzCore + 1032931) [0x7fff817be2e3]
                5    CA::Render::decode_commands(CA::Render::Decoder*) + 2276 (QuartzCore + 1030108) [0x7fff817bd7dc]
                  3    CA::Render::Context::did_commit(bool, bool) + 76 (QuartzCore + 750372) [0x7fff81779324]
                    2    CA::Render::post_notification(CA::Render::NotificationName, CA::Render::Object*, void*, bool) + 249 (QuartzCore + 104465) [0x7fff816db811]
                      2    contextChanged + 127 (CoreGraphics + 5099842) [0x7fff91bf3142]
                        2    mach_msg_trap + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 70534) [0x7fff8f639386]
                         *2    hndl_mach_scall64 + 22 (kernel + 2030166) [0xffffff80003efa56]
                           *2    mach_call_munger64 + 410 (kernel + 1817898) [0xffffff80003bbd2a]
                             *2    mach_msg_overwrite_trap + 197 (kernel + 877285) [0xffffff80002d62e5]
                               *2    ipc_kmsg_send + 307 (kernel + 813363) [0xffffff80002c6933]
                                 *2    ipc_mqueue_send + 599 (kernel + 827767) [0xffffff80002ca177]
                                   *2    ipc_mqueue_post + 932 (kernel + 828756) [0xffffff80002ca554] (running)
                    1    CA::Render::post_notification(CA::Render::NotificationName, CA::Render::Object*, void*, bool) + 99 (QuartzCore + 104315) [0x7fff816db77b] (running)
                  1    CA::Render::post_notification(CA::Render::NotificationName, CA::Render::Object*, void*, bool) + 94 (QuartzCore + 104310) [0x7fff816db776] (running)
                  1    CA::Render::post_notification(CA::Render::NotificationName, CA::Render::Object*, void*, bool) + 249 (QuartzCore + 104465) [0x7fff816db811]
                    1    contextDidCommit + 125 (CoreGraphics + 5100116) [0x7fff91bf3254] (running)
                1    CA::Render::decode_commands(CA::Render::Decoder*) + 61 (QuartzCore + 1027893) [0x7fff817bcf35]
                  1    CA::Render::Context::will_commit() + 30 (QuartzCore + 163728) [0x7fff816e9f90]
                    1    CA::Render::post_notification(CA::Render::NotificationName, CA::Render::Object*, void*, bool) + 94 (QuartzCore + 104310) [0x7fff816db776] (running)
              1    CA::Render::Server::ReceivedMessage::run_command_stream() + 683 (QuartzCore + 1033047) [0x7fff817be357]
                1    x_mem_dealloc_chain + 35 (QuartzCore + 54163) [0x7fff816cf393] (running)
```

The title line claims `1000 samples`, so I'm going to guess that the number in front of the stack frames is a count of how many times the sampler found that frame in the snapshot? That would also explain the indentation. What does the `*` next to the sample number mean? For example, `hndle_mach_scall64` has `*2` next to it. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it again, it seems like the `*` denotes code on the other side of a syscall.

Comment: Did you find a way to analyze stackshots?

Comment: Nothing beyond what I said here - the number does indeed seem to be the sample count, and the * does seem to be the part of the call stack extending into the kernel. That was enough for my needs.